# org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver not found

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am trying to connect Apache Artemis with Apache Camel in Spring Boot project.

I am getting problem when I am upgrading my spring boot version from 1.5.9.RELEASE to 2.2.2.RELEASE. Below is my POM and Java files which I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        
            <groupId>com.learncamel</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-learncamel-spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
        
            <name>learncamel-spring-boot</name>
            <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        
            <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
                <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
            </parent>
        
            <properties>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
                <java.version>1.8</java.version>
                <camel-version>2.20.1</camel-version>
            </properties>
        
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20.1</version>
                </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>
        
        
                <!--jdbc-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>${camel-version}</version>
                </dependency>
        
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>9.4.1212</version>
                </dependency>
        
        
        
                <!-- Lombok -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    <version>1.16.20</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
        
                <!-- EMail-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
        
        
                <!--activeMQ-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
        
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
                    <version>5.15.3</version>
                </dependency>
        
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20.1</version>
                </dependency>
        
                <!--health Check-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20.1</version>
                </dependency>
        
        
        
                <!--Test Dependencies-->
                <!--Camel Spring Test-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20.1</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
        
                <!--Clean Up directory-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.2</version>
                </dependency>
        
        
            </dependencies>
        
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        
        
        </project>
```

When I am upgrading parent version to 2.2.2.RELEASE then it start giving below error:-

```
  Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    21-06-2020 15:39:11.614 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application run failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.learncamel.ActiveMQCamelApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.apache.camel.spring.boot.security.CamelSSLAutoConfiguration due to org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:597)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$900(ConfigurationClassParser.java:109)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:805)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:801)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:771)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:325)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:242)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
        at com.learncamel.ActiveMQCamelApplication.main(ActiveMQCamelApplication.java:10)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.apache.camel.spring.boot.security.CamelSSLAutoConfiguration due to org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:54)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:221)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:587)
        ... 19 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver
        at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.security.CamelSSLAutoConfiguration$Condition.getMatchOutcome(CamelSSLAutoConfiguration.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
        ... 22 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am using below Java files:

```
package com.learncamel.config;
        
        import org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
        
        import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
        
        @Configuration
        public class ActiveMQConfig {
        
            @Bean(name="activemq")
            public ActiveMQComponent createComponent(ConnectionFactory  factory){
        
                ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
                activeMQComponent.setConnectionFactory(factory);
                return activeMQComponent;
        
            }
        }
```

Another Java file:

```
package com.learncamel.routes;
        
        import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
        
        @Component
        public class ActiveMQRoute extends RouteBuilder{
        
        
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
        
        
                from("{{fromRoute}}")
                            .log("Read Message from activemQ ${body}")
                        .to("{{toRoute}}");
        
                }
        }
```

Comment: Reviewing your question.Could you please [update the description of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), add `java` tag and explain these Java files.

Comment: Please refrain from adding `>` quote devices pointlessly into questions.

Comment: In my case the cause was that I used a dependency intended for Spring Boot 1.5, which obviously has the class. The solution was to upgrade the dependency to a spring boot v2-compatible one.

Answer (score 10):

Such errors could arise because of **mixed Spring versions**.

Do a [Maven dependency tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) and check for mixed Spring versions (the one of the parent POM and other versions from transitive dependencies.

If you got mixed Spring versions in your dependency tree, fix them with [dependency management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) or similar Maven features.

Answer (score 0):

I had spring-boot-starter-parent version in pom as 2.3.10.RELEASE but added spring-boot dependency of 2.1.8.RELEASE. I had to remove version from there to make the error go away

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <!--<version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>-->
</dependency>
```